# Call function with parameters from jquery conextmenu

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm calling a function from my jquery-contextmenu sumbenu, passing a specific parameter depending on which option was clicked.

I'm generating that submenu according to a js object, which contains three names. It's suposed when I click on one of them, my function is called with that name as parameter, and then it's printed on console.

But it calls the function with just the last element and I don't know why. When I click on "john" or "Matt", it just displays "you pressed Petter".

Just like on this image:

[image]

Even when I've never clicked on "Petter", it just displays "you pressed Petter".

The code (I could put the fiddle here but I didn't found the jquery contextmenu link, I'll be glad if you share it to me, if it exists):

```
var obj = {"1":"john","2":"Matt","3":"Petter"};

function myFun(name){
    console.log("you pressed "+name);
}

$(function() {
$.contextMenu({
  selector: '.context-menu-one',
  autoHide: true,
  build: function($trigger, e) {
    var options = {
      items: {}
    }

    options.items["users"] = {name: "users", icon: "fa-circle", items: {}}

    for(var i in obj){
      options.items["users"].items[obj[i]] = {name: obj[i], icon: "fa-user", callback: function(){
        myFun(obj[i]);
      }}
    }

    return options;
  }
});
});
```

Sorry for my bad english and thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to closure in the javascript language. The reference to the variable `i` within the callback will be stored and called outside the scope as before, however, the loop will have run through and `i`, which is globally scoped, will always be equal to the last index. To fix this change your loop to work like this

```
for(var i in obj){
  (function(j) {
    options.items["users"].items[obj[j]] = {name: obj[j], icon: "fa-user", callback: function(){
        myFun(obj[j]);
      }
    }
  })(i);
}
```

this creates a new scope within the function that keeps closure over the loop and keeps the value of i equal to the index that is currently being itterated upon, allowing the menu to work properly.

Comment: Beautiful, ty so much!

Answer (score 1):

```
for(var i in obj){
  options.items["users"].items[obj[i]] = {
    name: obj[i], 
    icon: "fa-user", 
    callback: function(){
      myFun(obj[i]); // here is the problem
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is caused by js closure, which the **i** variable was captured in every callback in **for** loop.
So when you execute the callback when click the menu **i** will always be the same, because they are the same variable. And the value of **i** would be the value when **for** loop complete, which is "3" in your example.

Here is how you can do to avoid the problem by using IIFE(Immediately Invoked Function Expression)

```
for (var i in obj) {
  (function (i) {
     // here goes the code in your for loop
  })(i);
}
```